# SQL Import job caused disk full even if I had Auto storage increase is enabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have Auto storage increase enabled on my cloud sql instance. I was running an import job (import from csv) ~ 800GB of data.
This caused the disk to be full as the bin logs increased.

```
[ERROR] Disk is full writing '/mysql/binlog/mysql-bin.xxxx' (Errcode: -1651078976 - No space left on device). Waiting for someone to free space...
```

Can someone pleae help me understand why this happened ?
What's the ideal solution for this

Comment: If I am not mistaken bin logs increased because of your operation. Since you know the size of the data you will import to your db, it would be wisier to increase the storage of your database before the operation takes place and give some extra free space. Hope it helps.

Comment: @TasosV gotcha. 

But my question is why didn't the storage space increase automatically even though it's configured on the instance

Comment: My guess is because of your continuous changing needs for space, not sure if that's expected or not. In case you would like to learn more about you can either open a ticket on GCP support or open a [Public Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=0)

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as Community Wiki, due to based partially in the comments.

As you can check in the [Automatic Storage Increase](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#:%7E:text=If%20the%20available%20storage%20falls,the%20maximum%20of%2030%20TB.) documentation, if you have the setting to raise the size automatically, it will be increase every 30 seconds, but not in realtime. So, in your case, it might be going over the limit before the instance has the time to increase itself.  Besides that, bear in mind that there is a threshold of 25 GB that the instance can increase each time, so, in case you add more data, faster than the instance increases its size, you will face the issue.

I would recommend you to give it a try checking if you won't be adding data faster than the instance has its size increased and as mentioned in the comments, in case you know the size of the operation, to already set the size before the operation.